# look for multiple type of XCUIElement in swift

Tags: swift, xcuitest

I would like to locate two XCUIElements and no problem to find them in following code.

```
func cells(_ text:String) {
    app.cells.element(withLabelContaining: text).firstMatch
}

func text(_ text:String) {
    app.staticText.element(withLabelContaining: text).firstMatch
}
```

However, I would like to find a way to just use one query to look for multiple type of XCUIElement, how can I do it? I check the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementquery) but I cannot find any solution for it

different type of XCUIElement

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
```

the `app.staticText` is effectively a shortcut for

```
app.windows.descendants(matching: XCUIElement.ElementType.staticText)
```

Hence by analogy we can do this:

```
let typesToBeFound = [XCUIElement.ElementType.cell.rawValue, 
                      XCUIElement.ElementType.staticText.rawValue]
let predicateFormat = "elementType == %lu OR elementType == %lu"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: predicateFormat, argumentArray: typesToBeFound)
let result = app.windows.descendants(matching: XCUIElement.ElementType.any).matching(predicate)
```